# ¿Crear una carpeta oculta java?

Tags: java

Tengo un método que recibe una **ruta** para crear un archivo en esta y claro el directorio lo hago de esta forma.

```
    public static File createTempFile(String exteString, String nombre, String path) throws IOException {
        try {
            File file = new File(path + "\\" + nombre + exteString);
//--
            Path toCreatePath = Paths.get(file.toURI());
            if (!Files.exists(toCreatePath)) {
                Files.createDirectories(toCreatePath);
            }
            return file;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(ReportLog.getErrorBuilder(new Object(), e));
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Mi problema es que necesito de alguna forma **ocultar** este *directorio* es decir que este no pueda verse por el **usuario**, ya que va a contener información **secreta**

> (no explicitamente informacion confidencial solo información no
>   redundante para el usuario)

Creo que es posible ya que la clase `Files` contiene el metodo `isHidden` pero aun no se como indicarle al directorio que este oculto.

Comment: ¿Tu aplicación es solo para Win o quieres que se mantenga multiplataforma?

Comment: Por ahora el alcance es solo windows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Te paso un ejemplo con `java.nio` que encontré en este [sitio](http://resolvethis.com/how-to-make-a-file-hidden-in-java-on-windows/):

```
package com.resolvethis.nio;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.LinkOption;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

public class MakeFileHidden {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Path path = Paths.get("C:\\resolvethis", "testfile.txt");
            Boolean hidden = (Boolean) Files.getAttribute(path, "dos:hidden", LinkOption.NOFOLLOW_LINKS);
            if (hidden != null && !hidden) {
                Files.setAttribute(path, "dos:hidden", Boolean.TRUE, LinkOption.NOFOLLOW_LINKS);
                System.out.println("File is now hidden!");
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.err.println("Things went wrong: " + ex.getMessage());
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Habrá que tener cuidado si lo que quieres es multiplataforma.

Answer (score 1):

Así es , se le puede indicar el atributo `:hidden` haciendo uso del método [setAttribute()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#setAttribute(java.nio.file.Path,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object,%20java.nio.file.LinkOption...)) en la documentación está el ejemplo para esto , aplicado a su función solo seria

```
public static File createTempFile(String exteString, String nombre, String path) throws IOException {
        try {
            File file = new File(path + "\\" + nombre + exteString);
            Path toCreatePath = Paths.get(file.toURI());
            if (!Files.exists(toCreatePath)) {
                Files.createDirectories(toCreatePath);
                // Añadimos el atributo a la carpeta
                Files.setAttribute(file.toPath(), "dos:hidden", true);
            }
            return file;
        } catch (IOException e) {

        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: Gracias por la info extra @Dev. Joel conservaré la documentación

Comment: Perfecto. Saludos.

Answer (score 1):

[isHidden()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/attribute/DosFileAttributes.html) únicamente retorna un valor boolean para definir si tu atributo es presente

Otra opción además de la comentada por @Dev.Joel (Java 7+):

```
 Files.setAttribute(file.toPath(), "dos:hidden", true);
```

es mediante el comando [attrib](https://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/attrib.mspx?mfr=true) mediante `Runtime.exec()` (Java 6-):

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("attrib +h " + rutaDirectorio);
p.waitFor();
```

Comment: Si entiendo bien al ejecutar esto está enviando una orden directa a DOS?, Es decir es como si la escribiese en la consola cmd ?

Comment: Exacto, únicamente que se esta realizando desde Java mediante: Runtime.getRuntime().exec( ... );

Comment: Ok esto también es muy interesante gracias por contribuir @Jorgesys